# How to properly return a PDF inside a JSON response?

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-web-api2

I need to return two **PDF** file's inside my `WebApi 2` *response*, actually i'm doing it by simply sending the pdf file as a **Base64** `string` but my question was **if the approach was correct or if there is a better way to do so**..

Here is my constructor which my `Api` returns:

```
public class DCW
{
    public string numdoc { get; set; }
    public string pdf { get; set; }
    public string pdf_regalo { get; set; }

    public string Base64(string path)
    {
        // Method to convert pdf to Base64
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        string file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

        return file;
    }
}
```

And here is how my `controller` look's like:

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DriverController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public DCW Post([FromBody]Scontrino scontrino)
        {

            DCW dcw = new DCW();
            string pdf = dcw.Base64("C:/users/imytyuk/Desktop/TEST/XXX01_731378.pdf");
            string pdf_regalo = dcw.Base64("C:/users/imytyuk/Desktop/TEST/XXX01_731378_regalo.pdf");

            dcw.numdoc = "5454835";
            dcw.pdf = pdf;
            dcw.pdf_regalo = pdf_regalo;

            return dcw;


        }

    }
```

Actually the response is the following:

```
{
    "numdoc": "5454835",
    "pdf": "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",
    "pdf_regalo": "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"
}
```

Comment: simple answer is you dont...... i would return a file like a byte array like byte[]

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro please dont recommend this, blindly using byte array in json response is a bad idea. because in text representation it looks like this [123, 22, ...], so you use on average 4 bytes for 1 byte. So total size of http request is increased by 4.

Comment: @Irdis I would NOT use JSON to return a file... I would just return a byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. It's a legit way to transfer files, but there are several cons:

1. Base64 encoding adds overhead in space due to its text nature
2. In your approach server must load entire file into the memory and make actual conversion to base64 that can be avoided
3. In your approach you force browser to load entire file into the memory (actually it has to keep entire request), when client receives base64 encoded file, only way to construct download link is to manipulate with given base64 encoded string, something like `href="data:...;base64,asdasd` or using browser api.

To fix this I recommend you to create separate GET method's in your controller for each files and rewrite original method such that it will provide necessary info to construct download link in browser to the newly added methods, it might be just relative link to controller method instead of file content. In GET method you also suppose to use 
`Controller.File(Stream, String, String)` and path there `FileStream` to target file.

Of-course there might be different cases. And sometimes it's necessary to load entire file as base64 to the client browser, for example: cropping images, digital signatures. But if there is any possibility to avoid this it must be avoided.

Comment: Actually in my reality the API will be consumed by a Windows Application and not used in a website so i think that it will not affect the memory consumption by deconding and receiving Base64 data.. And actually once the file has been sent to the user it's instantly deleted from the server so i'm not going to store those files.. But actually how can i avoid as you said in point 2. to avoid loading entire file into memory?

Comment: In general, this concept is called Streams. In controller you can use `return File(new FileStream('path to file', FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), "application/pdf", "filename.pdf")`. FileStream properties allow you to control the size of inner buffer.

Comment: If you want to delete file after client downloaded file, if I remember correctly you should be able to copy `FileStream` to `this.Response.OutputStream` using `Stream.CopyTo Method` and then delete it. But you need to set appropriate headers before that.

Comment: Everything I said is not necessary and your approach is fine, but if you are going to work with files a lot I recommend to practice this technique because this is how files are designed to be transferred over http.